# What's the criteria for Indexed Views?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I recently made index on a highly used view but it resulted in increase in Total Execution Time.
Also bytes Sent/received from server incresed drastically.

There are no functions or reference of any other view in it, offcourse schemabinding is on,
just join from two tables.

I am puzzled what to do for increasing performance?

Comment: Is your query actually using the index? (You need to (be running Enterprise, Data Center or Developer Edition) or (specify `WITH (NOEXPAND)` when accessing the view))

Comment: I am using Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `NOEXPAND` query hint to use indexed view.

> Use NOEXPAND if you want to be sure to have SQL Server process a query
>   by reading the view itself instead of reading data from the base
>   tables. If for some reason SQL Server chooses a query plan that
>   processes the query against base tables when you'd prefer that it use
>   the view, consider using NOEXPAND..
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx

```
 SELECT Column1, Column2, ... FROM Table1, View1 WITH (NOEXPAND) WHERE ...
```